# Template error with django-photologue: 'Permission Denied'

Tags: django, django-templates, photologue

I'm in the process of re-setting up my Django development environment after reinstalling my OS. We use django-photologue with our project, which I installed using easy_install. However, I'm getting a template error on every template that has a photologue photo:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /newsroom/news/
>   Caught an exception while rendering:
>   (13, 'Permission denied')

One example of the line where the error is located:

```
<img src="{{ photo.get_list_url }}">
```

I'm totally stumped--I've used photologue for this project on many different platforms and have never had this problem. Google yields nothing. I'm currently using Jolicloud (based on Ubuntu Jaunty). I'm working with a pre-existing database, so all of the photo sizes and everything have already been set up.

Comment: And the web server user has access to the folder the photos are stored in? Stupid question, given it would need it to upload the photos, but thought I would ask since you've just reinstalled the OS.

Comment: But if it is a development environment my guess is they use Django development server which runs as the same user who started it. Have you tried to just chown photologues upload directory to yourself again? Could be the same user on the fresh system and the old one have different UID? Only guessing hard to tell without seeing `ls -l` output. But it's a silly guess...

Comment: But you could have all kinds of different problems if your old home directory hadn't sufficient access... so it's silly presumption. Does anything else needs write access to disk in your Django apps? Does that work?